# How to insert jsonb[] data into column using pg-promise

Tags: pg-promise

Given a table with a column of type `jsonb[]`, how do I insert a json array into the column?

Using the provided formatters `:array`, `:json` won't work in this instance - unless I am missing the correct combination or something.

```js
const links = [
    {
        title: 'IMDB',
        url: 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759'
    },
    {
        title: 'Rotten Tomatoes',
        url: 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/star_wars'
    }
];

 const result = await db.none(`INSERT INTO tests (links) VALUES ($1:json)`, [links]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need the library's `:json` filter in this case, as you need an array of JSON objects, and not a JSON with an array of JSON objects.

The former is formatted correctly by default, which then only needs `::json[]` type casting:

```js
    await db.none(`INSERT INTO tests(links) VALUES($1::json[])`, [links]);
```

**Other Notes**

- Use [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor) or event [query](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query) to output queries being executed, for easier diagnostics.
- Method [none](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#none) can only resolve with `null`, no point storing the result in a variable.
- Library `pg-promise` does not have any `:array` filter, see [supported filters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#formatting-filters).

Comment: thanks @vitaly-t - I tried $1:json[] not $1::json[]. What is the difference when the double :: vs single :

Comment: @Chev That's the library's formatting filter with `:` prefix, versus SQL type casting, which uses `::` prefix.